# How to set OnTouchListener to a view defined externally for an activity?

Tags: android

I have an activity which implements OntouchListener defined within it

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent event) {return true;}
```

for views which are defined inside the activity class I use

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(resource, "id", "main.com.pack");
imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(resID);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img1);
imageView.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

The above code works pretty well for all events.
though for functions which are defined in other classes where I am passing my activity where other views are created I am not able to assign the OntouchListener from the activity which I am passing to the function.

```
public class ViewImageSetter {
    ImageView imageView;
    public void setViews(Context context, Activity mainActivity) {
        int resID = context.getResources().getIdentifier(resource, "id", "main.com.pack");
        imageView = (ImageView) mainActivity.findViewById(resID);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img2);
        //what should go into this line:
        imageView.setOnTouchListener(mainActivity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have different options to do that:

- You set the Activity type of your `setViews()` method to the actual Activity type that implements the `OnTouchListener`: (MainActivity for example)

  ```
  public void setViews(Context context, MainActivity mainActivity) { ...
  ```
- You pass an `OnTouchListener` object to your `setViews()` method instead of an `Activity`:

  ```
  public void setViews(Context context, OnTouchListener mainActivity) { ...
  ```

  Note that you cannot use specific Activity methods like `findViewById()` in this case anymore.
- You assume that your Activity always implements the `OnTouchListener` interface, so you simply cast it to one:

  ```
  imageView.setOnTouchListener((OnTouchListener)mainActivity);
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what if I have various different activities and their implementations will this be a good practice??

Comment: @Rishabh yes, this should work with multiple different Activities. (Except of the first approach)